# Does using only plugins from twitter bootstrap make sense?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not currently using twitter bootstrap, but I do like some of the components. Does it make sense to use a few plugins from that framework when I'm not using the rest of the framework? bootstrap-alert.js for example. I'm also not sure how mutually exclusive the plugins are from the rest of the framework. Would i have to load everything to use a couple, in which case it probably would make more sense to look elsewhere for nice popovers etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the customise section of the website to create a smaller version of the framework with just the components you want to use. I've used a few of their components in conjunction with ExtJS to get the look I wanted. i.e. Buttons, Badges and Alerts.

[Customize Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html)